Can anyone explain me this concept of probability?
I have one doubt in the following concept of Probability.
We all know that:
$P($ getting an event $)+P($ not getting an event $)=1$
For e.g. : $P($ getting head in a coin toss $)+P($ getting tail in the same coin toss $)=1$.
Now no doubt this concept is correct.
Now if I say one question like:
If $P($ winning a match $)=0.6$, then find the $P($ losing the match $)$.
Now generally we will say that:
$P($ losing the match $)=(1-0.6)=0.4$
Now I can't understand that in case of any game why don't we consider
$P($ the match will be won after tie $)$ ?
Does $P($ winning a game $)$ means that the game is won in a single chance ?
Or Does it implies that the game is won, may be the game is won in a single chance or in $2^{nd}$ chance i.e. after tie ?
I want to know the accurate meaning of  $P($ winning a game $)$.

Not following.  Obviously the definition of "winning a game" depends on the rules of the game. There aren't any universal rules for how ties should be interpreted.  If you are asking "are winning and losing a game always mutually exclusive and exhaustive?" the answer is certainly no.  Some games have ties, some have stalemates, and so on.  It all depends on the rules of the game.

Yes exactly @lulu. Then I think that we should also consider the case $P($ the match will be won after a tie $)$. Because winning a game in the $1^{st}$ chance and winning a game after tie are different cases.

I am not seeing your point.  Obviously, in any situation, you have to consider all the possible outcomes, not just a subset of them.

Why my question is downvoted?

I did not downvote this, but I think your post is very unclear.   In any scenario in which there are more than two outcomes (say $A,B,C$ are all possible outcomes), you can not say  that $P(A)+P(B)=1$.  You can still say that $P(A)+P(A^c)=1$ though, since $A^c$ comprises all the possible outcomes other than $A$.

In your terms, while in some particular game you may not be able to assert that $P(win)+P(loss)=1$ you can still assert that $P(win)+P(not, win)=1$.   It's just that "not win" might be more complicated than simply "loss".

Thank you @lulu

What do you mean by "the match will be won after tie"?

The key point to understand is that the interpretation of $P(\text{winning a game})$ depends on how you define the possible outcomes.
Two Possible Outcomes (Win or Lose):

If a game can only end in a win or a loss, then:
$$
  P(\text{winning}) + P(\text{losing}) = 1
  $$
In this scenario, if $P(\text{winning}) = 0.6$, then $P(\text{losing}) = 0.4$.

Three Possible Outcomes (Win, Lose, or Tie):

If a game can end in a win, loss, or tie, then:
$$
  P(\text{winning}) + P(\text{losing}) + P(\text{tie}) = 1
  $$
In this case, $P(\text{losing})$ is calculated as:
$$
  P(\text{losing}) = 1 - P(\text{winning}) - P(\text{tie})
  $$

Both interpretations are correct, but it's up to you to be clear about whether a tie is a possible outcome. If ties are possible, you must include them in your probability calculations. Otherwise, you can use the simpler formula where $P(\text{losing}) = 1 - P(\text{winning})$.

Yes you are correct @Samuele Biscaro. But then I think that we can say that the formula $P($ getting an event $)$ + $P($ not getting an event $)$ is not always true, especially for any game.

Not really, if the event is "win" then not getting the event would be "lose or tie" and the formula still holds

@SubhaSankarRoy, I think you might be confusing what "not getting an event" means. If  possible outcomes are "win", "tie" and "lose" and the event is "win", then not getting the "win" means "tie or lose", it doesn't mean just "lose".

Yes now I understood correctly. @Ennar
